# How to customize the columns according to user in runtime

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

I am using dispaly-tag for showing data from the database in jsp. I am using Spring mvc, I want to customize the column in runtime as per the user. Is there any tag libraries that gives this facility of customizing column based on user

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this blog entry.  It uses jquery to show and hide the columns and persists the users settings in a cookie.

http://www.prodevtips.com/2010/09/09/showing-and-hiding-table-columns-with-jquery/